# Concatenate two mongodb collection

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have a very big collection with 7M+ documents with 12 indexes.
I am trying to historicize the documents and would like to have a smaller collection with only the documents that have a date field in the range of [-2 weeks, future], to speed up search queries.

However the data inside this collection, in some cases, is queried even for those documents for which the date field is older than 2 weeks.

The ideas I thought of were:

- Create a parallel collection with a TTL index and updated it with a trigger. **Cons**: it could be very expensive in terms of costs since this collection is frequently accessed and used only for the needed query.
- Create a materialized view that contains only the data I need. **Cons**: doesn't provide near-real-time results since I need to call the update function every once in a while.

The last idea I could come up with was to find a way to split the two collections: the current, with only fresh data (i.e.: last two weeks + future or last month + future) and transfer documents from one to another every once in a while.
Then, programmatically "merge" the two collections when queries need to have the past data as well.

What is the best way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend your both approachs, looks really inconsistent,

I think you need to look into the time-series collection of the MongoDB starting from Version 5.0,
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/

All the details are explained in the above documentation, read this for quick information,

> Time series collections behave like normal collections. You can insert and query your data as you normally would.
>
> MongoDB treats time series collections as writable non-materialized views backed by an internal collection. When you insert data, the internal collection automatically organizes time series data into an optimized storage format.
>
> When you query time series collections, you operate on one document per measurement. Queries on time series collections take advantage of the optimized internal storage format and return results faster.
>
> **Reduced complexity for working with time series data**
>
> - Improved query efficiency
> - Reduced disk usage
> - Reduced I/O for read operations
> - Increased WiredTiger cache usage

I can't say how to migrate your old data into time-series collections, you have to check that.

---

Second, if the above approach is not working for you for some reason or if you are using an older version of MongoDB, then I would recommend you to create dynamic collections date or month or year wise, or any property that groups the small number of documents,

For Ex: if we store monthly collection, the collection would be:

```
collection_01_2022 // jan
collection_02_2022 // feb
collection_03_2022 // mar
```

For Ex: if we store yearly collection, the collection would be:

```
collection_2020
collection_2021
collection_2022
```

That property is required in each request from your portal so you can search on that specific dynamic collection.

Comment: I'm considering moving to version 5.0 for the timeseries which should give me some advantage in this kind of problem, however it requires some migration.

For the second solution it is not viable because that way I won't be able to query "between" the two collections, i.e. getting records both from jan and feb, or all of them.

Comment: I had same issue resolved by time-series

Comment: @Mani Joshi, was the migration difficult to manage? Could you please explain it a little better the method you adopted?